# Making a Parallel Sorting Algorithm Faster than Naive Optimized Quicksort?

Tags: c, multithreading, performance, algorithm, sorting

As the title suggests, I need to make an algorithm that is faster than quicksort. The quicksort in question is optimized and used in a naive paralleled system so that a single thread completely does each quicksort but multiple threads are doing a quicksort at the same time. I need to make an algorithm that is faster than this process. Would it be faster to parallel each quicksort by having additional threads execute the sorting of each side of a pivot or would this process have too much overhead and end up causing a slow down? Any suggestions for an algorithm?

Comment: Once you have an inital partition, splitting the sorting of sub-sections over different threads is a natural thing to do and should give you a speedup if cores are available.

Comment: Using additional threads to sort each sub-section will definitely speed up a single quicksort but my question was regarding a speedup in successive quicksorts in a system.

Comment: For example, if one has 4 1.0 GHZ processors then the throughput of the system is 4.0 GHZ. If you do naive parallelization then each quicksort will complete in the time that it takes for a 1.0 GHZ processor to complete it but 4 are being completed at the same time. If you parallel each quicksort then each quicksort will take as long as a 4.0 GHZ processor would take to complete it, however only 1 of these would be executing at a single time.

Comment: I think it depends on the number of processors you have available. If you are doing N quicksorts at once and you only have N processors with 1 thread handling each quicksort, then making each individual quicksort multithreaded will only slow down your code because of unnecessary overhead. On the other hand if you do have additional processors available, then the processors will compensate for additional overhead and you will probably see an increase in speed.

Comment: The number of quicksorts in my system is far larger than the number of processors so the ramp-down time of the computations is negligible.

Answer (score 6):

If I understand correctly, you currently have a system in which N sorts are performed by N threads. Each individual sort is done by a single thread, but there can be multiple sorts running concurrently. You're asking if it would be faster to write a parallel sorting algorithm so that each sort is performed by multiple threads.

So let's say that you have four processors and you have to do 10 sorts. Assuming that each sort takes the same amount of time (unrealistic, but useful for discussion), then if each sort runs in a single thread you can have four sorts running at once. Call the time to perform one single-threaded sort one time period.

So the time to do all sorts will be three time periods. During two periods you have four sorts running concurrently, and during one period you have two concurrent sorts. You have excess capacity (two idle processors) during that last time period.

If you have a parallel sorting algorithm that uses four threads, then the best case is that each sort will take 1/4 the time of a single-threaded sort. So in theory you can perform the 10 sorts in 10/4 time periods, meaning that it will take only 2.5 time periods.

So in theory you could save half of a time period by going to a parallel sorting algorithm. But you won't realize that much of a performance gain because quicksort isn't 100% parallelizable; there are times when fewer than four threads will be involved. You have idle processors at random times during each sort. It's quite possible that using the parallel version will be slower overall because those small bits of idle time add up.

Think of it this way: you have four people who need to do 10 jobs. They can do those 10 jobs by each taking one and doing it individually, or by cooperating so that each of the four does 1/4 of the work on each job. There is no difference in the amount of work done. In the first case you have two idle workers while the last two jobs are being done. In the second case, you have some idle time while the last job is being done; worker 1 is idle 3/4 of the time period, worker 2 is idle for 1/2 the time period, and worker 3 is idle for 1/4 of the time period. So in theory your total worker idle time is 6/4, or 1.5 time periods.

But there's also idle time involved in moving a job from worker 1 to worker 2, etc. That transition time has both workers idle briefly. Those small bits of time (3 transitions per job, plus time for worker 1 to get the next job and start, and the time for worker 4 to deliver the finished product) add up, and could quite possibly exceed the .5 time periods that are ostensibly saved.

You could give it a try, though. It's pretty easy to parallelize quicksort. See, for example, http://reedcopsey.com/2010/02/26/parallelism-in-net-part-11-divide-and-conquer-via-parallel-invoke/.

Comment: Thanks! As a random aside, do you know the term for making an algorithm itself parallel vs naive parallelization which is running multiple instances of a non paralleled algorithm concurrently? (i.e. what is the opposite of naive parallelization?)

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the size and nature of the data.  QS has worst case performance on sorted data (if memory serves).  As you suggest you could provide a thread for each side of the pivot but you would want to limit that your partitions don't become too small.  Please follow up and let us know how it goes, I'd be interested in knowing and I'm sure others would too.

Comment: The data is completely random and size of it is random in magnitude. The QS algorithm is already optimized so that it will perform insertion sort when it is more efficient (at smaller sizes).

Comment: As I stated in a comment of the OP, I was worried as to whether or not parallelization of each QS would actually yield a faster throughput because each QS would be done much faster but less sorts would be done at any given time (all of the processor's cores have a maximum throughput potential).

Comment: That's up to Amdahl's law (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law).  General questions like this can be quite complex because if you have a lot of processors memory overhead can be an issue.  I assume you have an  Intel CPU with somewhere between 4-16 (HT)cores.  Optimization of the QS algo wasn't my concern for the partition, it was that you want the thread to have enough work to pay for the overhead of creation/use.  So the last n pivots will be done on the same thread (often you have to experiment to determine the threshold)